# Compare empty array

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a program that takes a list of floating point numbers representing distance in inches and converts them to shoe sizes to the nearest 0.5.

I'm trying to compare an empty list and expect the output to be The list is empty.  Instead I don't return any value.  Not sure where I'm going wrong?

```
foot_length = []

for length in foot_length:
    if length == 0:
        print('The list is empty.')
    else:
        convert_to_shoe_size = length * 3 - 23
        round_shoe_size = round(convert_to_shoe_size * 2, 2) / 2
        print(round_shoe_size)
```

I've tried a number of different approaches none of which get the output I want/expect.

```
if not length:
    print('The list is empty.')

if len(length) == 0:
    print('The list is empty.')
```

Comment: Before you enter the loop: `if len(foot_length) == 0: print('The list is empty.')` then put the loop in the `else`.

Comment: `len(foot_length )` gives the length of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code to

```
foot_length = []

if len(foot_length) == 0:
    print('The list is empty.')
else:
    for length in foot_length:
        convert_to_shoe_size = length * 3 - 23
        round_shoe_size = round(convert_to_shoe_size * 2, 2) / 2
        print(round_shoe_size)
```

Comment: I did think of doing this but for some reason didn't go ahead and try it. That will teach me to trust my instincts more. Thank you